# Angular 2 datatable install error

Tags: angular, npm

How do I fix the unmet peer dependencies when I try to install the angular 2 data table?

This is what I get when I try to install it.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peer dependencies mean other dependencies we need to install in our application to function correctly
npm does not install peer dependencies for us.so we have to install them manually.
as a example you need to install them like this

```
npm install --save @angular/common
npm install --save @angular/core
npm install --save @angular/platform-browser
```

sometimes you can solve it by deleting and re-installing npm packages.like this.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```

---

check these data tables.I have used this data table for my developments.
https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table